# Faster way to remove element from dict if contain some words

Tags: python, optimization

I want to remove element contain specific words in my dictionary for example:

```
my_dict = {
    "this is a first example" : 5,
    "this is a seconde example" : 3,
    "this is a third example" : 2
}

my_list = ["first", "third"]
```

The result that I want is this:

```
{'this is a seconde example': 3}
```

This is what I do:

```
my_new_dict = dict(my_dict)

for sent in my_dict:
    for word in sent.split() :
        if word in my_list :
            del my_new_dict[sent]
            break
```

This script works but the problem is that it is very long,
for a dictionary of size 1 Million and a word list of size 355K it takes more than six hours.

Is there any better method?

Answer (score 5):

What's really slowing down your code is the use a list for lookups, which takes *O(n)* in average time complexity. Converting it to a set alone would speed up the code dramatically since it turns lookups into an *O(1)* operation.

Secondly, deleting individual keys from a dict also incurs quite a bit of overhead, since each key lookup requires hashing and searching. Building a new dict by leaving out keys that contain unwanted words would be a lot more efficient.

```
my_set = set(my_list)
my_new_dict = {
    sent: count
    for sent, count in my_dict.items()
    if not any(word in my_set for word in sent.split())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion but im sure it will be much faster, Hopefully will work for you :

```
my_dict = {
    "this is a first example" : 5,
    "this is a seconde example" : 3,
    "this is a third example" : 2
}

my_list = ["first", "third"]

my_new_dict = dict(my_dict)

for sent in my_dict

     dict_contains_value= any(element in sent for element in my_dict)

     if (dict_contains_value) :
            del my_new_dict[sent]
            break
```